# Right alignment of controls inside a horizontally oriented stackview in uistoryboard

Tags: uiview, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uistackview

I have a StackView (Card View) with vertical orientation, alignment and distribution are "Fill".

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

Inside that I have a few more StackViews with horizontal orientation and a few other controls. In that, the last StackView with Horizontal Orientation, Alignment = Top and Distribution = Fill, has two buttons for "Save" and "Cancel"

XML for last stackview:

```
<stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="right" alignment="top" spacing="15" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="qk0-Aa-LVy">
<rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="301" width="414" height="51"/>
<subviews>
    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="wordWrap" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TzA-jj-KRx">
        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="199.66666666666666" height="31"/>
        <inset key="contentEdgeInsets" minX="10" minY="10" maxX="10" maxY="10"/>
        <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
        <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Save" buttonSize="medium"/>
    </button>
    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xHU-No-XcV">
        <rect key="frame" x="214.66666666666663" y="0.0" width="199.33333333333337" height="31"/>
        <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
        <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Cancel"/>
    </button>
</subviews>
<constraints>
    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="TzA-jj-KRx" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="d5Z-DX-Keg"/>
</constraints>
```

[image: Screenshot with stackview properties]

I want the two buttons to right align and I don't know how to get that. I use Xamarin.iOS.

Please note, There may be some unwanted constrains and other code as this was my first learning project. Please let me know more lines from xml is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the **Leading** constraint from your "bottom stack view"

Comment: But the "bottom stack view " has only bottom constraint, right?

<constraints>
    <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="TzA-jj-KRx" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="d5Z-DX-Keg"/>
</constraints>

Can you please show me in the picture Which one to delete? Thanks

Comment: Ah - I didn't catch the full layout from your pics (think I was distracted by all the unnecessary constraints). Posted an answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First tip: Change the default names of your UI elements to make it easy to understand the Hierarchy in the Document Outline pane.

It looks like you have ***a lot*** of unnecessary constraints...

I laid out a controller to match yours (well, at least close) - here's how it looks:

[image]

The horizontal stack view containing the Save/Cancel buttons is an arranged subview of `Card Stack View` ... which has `Alignment: Fill` which means the `Buttons Stack View` will be stretched to the full width.

If you want the  buttons to "right align" you need to embed `Buttons Stack View` in a `UIView` - I'll name it `BtnStack Holder View` - and constrain `Buttons Stack View` Top, Bottom & Trailing (but not Leading).

That gives us this (I gave `BtnStack Holder View` a Yellow background to make it easy to see):

[image]

Here is the source for that Storyboard:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="22154" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="22130"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="s0d-6b-0kx">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Y6W-OH-hqX" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="5EZ-qb-Rvc">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="R7A-M2-45j" userLabel="Root Stack View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="334"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cxs-Xz-vJJ" userLabel="Logo Image View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="60"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="60" id="5bf-RF-cow"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="16" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="IV2-Ac-KTt" userLabel="Card Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="72" width="375" height="262"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="tkJ-N8-lmn" userLabel="A Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="31"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1iP-4F-fXh">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="51" height="31"/>
                                                    </switch>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Allow me to track your location" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="LdZ-fZ-8eB">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="61" y="0.0" width="314" height="31"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NbU-Ac-LPE" userLabel="B Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="47" width="375" height="31"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wJh-5f-Rzb">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="51" height="31"/>
                                                    </switch>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Allow me to use the camera to scan QR codes" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="VhU-SK-Ehb">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="61" y="0.0" width="314" height="31"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="12" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4Eh-cj-Eyk" userLabel="C Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="94" width="375" height="31"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <switch opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="750" verticalHuggingPriority="750" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" on="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cbM-V2-q1x">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="51" height="31"/>
                                                    </switch>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Allow me to use NFC connections" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="i7Y-61-XAS">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="61" y="0.0" width="314" height="31"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Customer identifier:" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ODr-EE-p48" userLabel="Host Name Label">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="141" width="375" height="20.5"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                            </label>
                                            <textField opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="248" contentHorizontalAlignment="left" contentVerticalAlignment="center" text="temp" borderStyle="roundedRect" textAlignment="natural" minimumFontSize="17" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GFT-dj-GNZ" userLabel="Host Name Text">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="177.5" width="375" height="34"/>
                                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                                <textInputTraits key="textInputTraits"/>
                                            </textField>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kFD-Sc-UIQ" userLabel="BtnStack Holder View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="227.5" width="375" height="34.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Xdd-6y-H1j" userLabel="Buttons Stack View">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="214" y="0.0" width="161" height="34.5"/>
                                                        <subviews>
                                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2Yh-up-7dE">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="76.5" height="34.5"/>
                                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Save"/>
                                                            </button>
                                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" verticalHuggingPriority="1000" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="V7g-sC-sGu">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="84.5" y="0.0" width="76.5" height="34.5"/>
                                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Cancel"/>
                                                            </button>
                                                        </subviews>
                                                    </stackView>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99953407049999998" green="0.98835557699999999" blue="0.47265523669999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="Xdd-6y-H1j" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kFD-Sc-UIQ" secondAttribute="top" id="LlS-5v-cXp"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Xdd-6y-H1j" secondAttribute="bottom" id="buF-cZ-29y"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Xdd-6y-H1j" secondAttribute="trailing" id="lVb-UW-eYo"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="vDu-zF-Fre"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="R7A-M2-45j" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="leading" id="6QS-yP-c87"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="vDu-zF-Fre" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="R7A-M2-45j" secondAttribute="trailing" id="fFV-cY-YXj"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="R7A-M2-45j" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="vDu-zF-Fre" secondAttribute="top" id="yAh-lU-Ojw"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Ief-a0-LHa" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="28" y="4.9475262368815596"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two buttons to right align, you can create a parent UIView and then add two children UIView within it respectively to make the two buttons align right. I made a small demo, you can refer to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="21701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_12" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="21679"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="spr-Nj-etT">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="Guk-rI-Gf8" customClass="ViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="KYh-z1-5xj"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="zwR-AE-XVK"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="P0e-PR-rP8">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="393" height="852"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="jIo-mB-Hep" userLabel="ViewSupper">
                                <rect key="frame" x="3.6666666666666572" y="366.66666666666669" width="386" height="119"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="hou-Hd-LV5" userLabel="ViewFirst" colorLabel="IBBuiltInLabel-Green">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="190.33333333333334" height="119"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="wm0-Je-5sg">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="115.33333333333331" y="37.333333333333314" width="75" height="44"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="44" id="MaV-yf-fwZ"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Button"/>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemGreenColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="wm0-Je-5sg" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="hou-Hd-LV5" secondAttribute="centerY" id="RDm-XQ-tL2"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="wm0-Je-5sg" secondAttribute="trailing" id="rNO-sv-6Lp"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="22h-St-obH" userLabel="ViewSecond">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="190.33333333333337" y="0.0" width="195.66666666666663" height="119"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="system" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="egB-Xx-Pte">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="120.66666666666669" y="37.333333333333314" width="75" height="44"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="44" id="FKH-MZ-qtN"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                                <state key="normal" title="Button"/>
                                                <buttonConfiguration key="configuration" style="plain" title="Button"/>
                                            </button>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemPinkColor"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="egB-Xx-Pte" secondAttribute="trailing" id="joD-7q-Baa"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="egB-Xx-Pte" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="22h-St-obH" secondAttribute="centerY" id="tAZ-iF-4o0"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemOrangeColor"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="22h-St-obH" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="jIo-mB-Hep" secondAttribute="top" id="2E4-pq-d40"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hou-Hd-LV5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="jIo-mB-Hep" secondAttribute="top" id="2I4-Ck-kQo"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hou-Hd-LV5" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="jIo-mB-Hep" secondAttribute="centerY" id="9s3-uN-g73"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="22h-St-obH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hou-Hd-LV5" secondAttribute="trailing" id="CzH-c3-dvZ"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="22h-St-obH" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Hpj-cG-73v"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="22h-St-obH" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="hou-Hd-LV5" secondAttribute="trailing" id="It0-q1-ijW"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hou-Hd-LV5" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="jIo-mB-Hep" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.492228" constant="0.5" id="O2s-bs-iXt"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="119" id="dLz-AL-dDk"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="386" id="e2p-io-yC7"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="hou-Hd-LV5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="jIo-mB-Hep" secondAttribute="leading" id="f4B-CY-DTJ"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="hou-Hd-LV5" secondAttribute="bottom" id="hy9-jf-Coc"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="22h-St-obH" secondAttribute="bottom" id="syj-GC-MaV"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="jIo-mB-Hep" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="P0e-PR-rP8" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Hij-uC-gfu"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="jIo-mB-Hep" firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="P0e-PR-rP8" secondAttribute="centerY" id="oLW-Cv-X0i"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="XcU-Kh-a1t" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1052.6717557251909" y="14.084507042253522"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <systemColor name="systemGreenColor">
            <color red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.7803921568627451" blue="0.34901960784313724" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemOrangeColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.58431372549019611" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemPinkColor">
            <color red="1" green="0.17647058823529413" blue="0.33333333333333331" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.